# stop a function on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with a jquery function.
When I launch my page, my progress bars come alive as expected, but they come alive without ever stopping ... I would like the code to run once.
here is the code and the function.
Thank you very much for your help.

here is the code

```
function loadBar() {
    var delay = 500;
    $(".progress-bar").each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(delay * i).animate({
            width: $(this).attr('aria-valuenow') + '%'
        }, delay);

        $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: delay,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function(now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%');
            }
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    // au clic sur un lien

    $('#webLangages').on('click', function() {

        loadBar();
    });
});


var target = $("#third").offset().top;
var interval = setInterval(function(event) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > target) {
        //start loading progress bar
        loadBar();
        loadBar.stopNow();
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

Comment: thank you for your reply.
when i use setTimeout, my code will not run anymore ...

Comment: What changes your `$(".progress-bar").text()`? You should update progress bar during progress change (ajax)...or atleast clearInterval when it finishes..